# Dealing with SimpleDateFormat passed in RequestBody

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, simpledateformat

I'm developing a simple REST Controller. I'm receiving a SimpleDateFormat object in Request body. Looks like that:

```
2014-04-13T03:42:06-02:00
```

My current method now is:

```
@PostMapping
        public ResponseEntity<Flight> addFlight(@RequestBody JSONObject object) {
            Flight newFlight = new Flight(object.get("flightNumber").toString(), new 
            SimpleDateFormat ( object.get("departureDate").toString()));
            repository.save(newFlight);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(newFlight);
        }
```

And class

```
@Data
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Flight {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private final String flightNumber;
    private final SimpleDateFormat date;
}
```

Everything is compiling fine, but when I'm sending POST or GET I receive all of the data that I've passed, but SimpleDateFormat is null. How could I repair it?
I've also tried to pass Object to FlightClass and then use a converter in the class's constructor, but I've still had null.

Comment: That is a date **not** a dateformat.

Comment: A `SimpleDateFormat` is an object that you use to format and parse dates = convert date and time objects to and from strings. You're not receiving a `SimpleDateFormat` object in a request. Instead, you are receiving a string that you want to convert to a date and time object.

Comment: I would recommend to use `Instant` instead

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer.

Comment: This is a design error and will never work: `private final SimpleDateFormat date;`. A `SimpleDateFormat` could never represent a date. Here too you want either `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is a legacy class and i would recommend [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) since your input represents ISO-8601 with offset

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(object.get("departureDate").toString());
```